# how to use the installed python package from command line on window 7

Tags: python-3.x

I download the external python package called morfessor and installed using `pip install morfessor`. To use the package there are command line commands such as `morfessor-train`, the syntax is:

```
morfessor-train --encoding=ISO_8859-15 --traindata-list --logfile=log.log -s model.bin -d ones traindata.txt
```

I tried by specifying the path into the folder where the commands are available,
as: `C:\Python34\Scripts\Morfessor-2.0.3\scripts`
the error here occur is "morfessor-train is not recognized as an internal and external command, operable program or batch file"

when I tried also using the `python -m  mofessor-train`. but it said that "no module named morfessor-train"

how can run or use the commands from the command line to access the package?

Comment: A module shouldn't have an hyphen in it's name

Comment: How did you "specify the path into the folder", and what error did you get? Please edit your question to show us *exactly* what you tried.